# Jenkins CSP self works in Firefox but not Chrome or Safari

Tags: html, css, jenkins, content-security-policy

Our private Jenkins server provides a [Content Security Policy](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy) on the pages it serves up, and I'm trying to get it to work with the Clover HTML code coverage reports that it serves up.

The [default Jenkins CSP](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Configuring+Content+Security+Policy#ConfiguringContentSecurityPolicy-TheDefaultRuleSet) allows `'self'` for images and styles:

> sandbox; default-src 'none'; img-src 'self'; style-src 'self';

`'self'` "allows loading resources from the same origin (same scheme, host and port)," according to [content-security-policy.com](https://content-security-policy.com/#source_list).

The Clover reports include relative CSS and image links, and since they're relative, they use the same scheme, host, and port:

```
  <link href="_css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

In spite of this, Chrome rejects them:

> Refused to load the stylesheet 'http://jnk.internal.example.com:8080/job/MyProject/lastStableBuild/cloverphp-html/_css/bootstrap.min.css' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "style-src 'self'". Note that 'style-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'style-src' is used as a fallback.

Safari refuses to load them with a similar error. Firefox, however, is just fine.

Why doesn't `'self'` work, when the documentation I've read makes it sound like it should? Why does Firefox work when Chrome and Safari don't?